# Ford F150 XL - How do the vehicle control modes work?

Tags: ford, f-150, control

My 2018 F150 has multiple driving modes:

> Normal | Snow/Wet | Eco | Sport

I understand Snow/Wet is for wet surfaces, etc, etc.

But what exactly are they doing to the drive-train?   What widgets are they engaging or disengaging?

How does Eco mode give you better mileage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driving modes programmatically adjust the transmission.

The transmission is electronically controlled, which means that the computer always controls when the engine downshifts or upshifts. The decision is made based on RPM, load, throttle position, and other sensor inputs. The settings allow you to adjust the feel of the driving experience.

- Normal - default tune.
- Snow/Wet - enables 4-wheel drive if available, and adjusts transmission for more consistent and predictable shift points.
- Eco - lowers RPM at which the transmission shifts, which increases fuel economy.
- Sport - increases RPM at which the transmission shifts, which improves driving experience.